# Invoice number in create_with_paypal node sdk PayPal

Tags: node.js, sails.js, paypal

I'm using [Create PayPal SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK/blob/master/samples/payment/create_with_paypal.js) to make a transaction using paypal and redirecting the user to paypal.

I'm using the same code as per suggested in above link, but i want to send invoice number with create paypal to be shown under transaction detail. but i am not able to find how can i send a invoice number to paypal.

Please guide me if there is any object in which i can sent the invoice number to [Create PayPal SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK/blob/master/samples/payment/create_with_paypal.js) OR any other method through which i can sent invoice number to PayPal.

**Note:** this project is in sailsjs.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check this: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK/blob/master/samples/invoice/send.js

```
var invoiceId = "INV2-GLJ8-9FA2-26BB-GHLU";

paypal.invoice.send(invoiceId, function (error, rv) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error.response);
        throw error;
    } else {
        console.log("Send Invoice Response");
        console.log(rv);
    }
});
```

Please look at the complete invoice example here, there is everything you need: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK/tree/master/samples/invoice

As per documentation you can handle your custom IDs:

> For exploring additional payment capabilites, such as handling
>   discounts, insurance, soft_descriptor and invoice_number, have a look
>   at this [example](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK/blob/master/samples/payment/create_with_paypal_further_capabilities.js). These bring REST payment functionality closer to
>   parity with older Merchant APIs. https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK

Comment: { name: 'RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND_ERROR',
  message: 'invoice with id INV2-GLJ8-9FA2-26BB-GHLU not found in the system.',

  debug_id: 'dbbc9c08fb74c',
  httpStatusCode: 404 }

Comment: i'm trying to send invoice number before create request, i think there is sequence issue. what do yous say?

Comment: actually i need to send invoice id which I've generated in my application like we do in payflow so that later i can check the transaction on paypal side for the details, but for this i think i first had to create invoice id then send it to paypal like you did and then create paypal so that i can get redirect url,

but the point is how paypal will know that this transaction id is for specific transaction ? also let me know if this transaction id will be shown under paypal website transaction detail

Comment: Because you have to create it before send, when you create it you receive a response with the right ID you have to use to send it. https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK/blob/master/samples/invoice/create.js

Comment: then 1) how paypal will get to know that this invoice id is against this order ? 2) does this invoice num will be shown in detail of transaction in paypal website ?

Comment: Look at this: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK/blob/master/samples/payment/create_with_paypal_further_capabilities.js YOU create the create_payment_json object and you send it to Paypal, of course you need to create the transaction before trying to create/send the invoice (but this is logic I think)